# Transit visa in Bangkok

Tags: transit

My son is going to Auckland, New Zealand from Mumbai, India via Bangkok, Thailand with Thai Airways. Does he need a transit visa? His layover is 14 hours at Bangkok airport.

Comment: Thai Airways charges a very low fee for changes. Would you consider the possibility of changing his flight so that the layover time is lesser? 14 hours on an airport feel like never ending and might be a little too inconvenient if it’s his first time solo experience.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming he is an Indian citizen, as long as your son stays in the secure area, he won't need a visa to transit in Suvarnabhumi.

Since he's flying with Thai Airways all the way, his luggage will be checked through. All he has to do is pass through security again, and go up to the departure level. And wait, a long time.

There are many restaurants and rest areas in BKK, so he won't really go hungry, and will have a place to sleep.